# How to add the Cart button on top of the page in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a site using Wordpress+Woocommerce

I am having a problem here, how to add the cart on top of the page that will dynamically change the number of products and price, each time a user adds a product to cart?

Currently I am trying with this code, but no luck yet:

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

function woocommerce_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    ob_start();

    ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>
    <?php

    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

}
```

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Hi Ronny, I have added the code with the question, please check and let me know if you can help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code at top of your page header.

you have to declar this first : 
`<?php global $woocommerce; ?>` //required !!!!

And then put this wherever you want the total number of items to appear :

```
<?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?>
```

if someone want to print the total ( $ ) like me you can put this code :

```
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
```

and here is the cart url too :

```
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>
```

That's all .

Comment: ok, that works but I need to refresh the page each time to see whether the product has been add to the cart, can't we do some thing so that it will be refreshed automatically??

And one more thing how can I link that to the Viewcart page?

Comment: Use onclick events in Javascript.

Comment: No problem I figured it out,

<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e('View your shopping cart', 'woothemes'); ?>"><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a>

Comment: :), okay its all yours!!

Comment: Thank you :) Keep it up.